# Ajax.BeginForm redirect to control

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Ajax.BeginForm redirect to control**

I'm created a MVC 4 application using razor. Following code is used on my form to submit data.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Topup", "Card", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "Submitting_Form", OnComplete = "Submitted_Form", UpdateTargetId = "SendStatus"}, new { id="FormSubmit"})) 
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Mobile Topup</li>

        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MobileNo)            
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNo)            
        </li>    


        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label class="ui-input-text" id="SendStatus">Test</label>            
        </li>

        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="submit" value="Topup" />
            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset(); $('#TopupDate').val(Current_Date('d-m-y'));" />
        </li>        



        <!--<li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>-->
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
}
```

On Controller

```
 //[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Topup(TopupModel model)
        {
            try { 

            }
            catch (Exception ExC) {
                Bug.Bug BG = new Bug.Bug();
                BG.Send_Bug_Message(ExC);
            }
            //return PartialView("PartialTopup", model);
            return Content("Success");
        }
```

But after submitting, page is automatically redirected to Controller (e.g., `http://localhost:43289/Card/Topup` with a string "Undefined"

Why is this happening?  I'm already included following libraries.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js"></script>
```

After inspecting with Firebug, I got some clue.

```
POST http://localhost:43289/Card/Topup?Length=4 200 OK 114ms jquery-2.0.3.js (line 7845)
POST http://localhost:43289/Card/Topup?Length=4 200 OK 113ms jquery-2.0.3.js (line 7845)
```

It happened twice.  Why?
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your'e using the wrong overload, right now your `AjaxOptions` is in the route value parameter,
use this instead:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Topup", "Card", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "Submitting_Form", OnComplete = "Submitted_Form", UpdateTargetId = "SendStatus"}, new { id="FormSubmit"}))
```

When you see the Length query string, it's actually a hint that you are using the incorrect parameters.

UPDATE:

The only reason I can think of why it's posting twice right now is that you are referencing your scripts twice. Don't put scripts in your partial. Just place it in the main view or your `layout` view